# Java equals() method for inherited objects

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
class Car {
    Piece doors;
    Piece window;
    String name;
    List<Sign> signs; //???

    Car() {

    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //...
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (other == null || other.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.doors == other.doors && this.window == other.window ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Piece extends Car {
    Piece() {
        //...

    }
}

class Brand extends Car {

    Brand(String name, Sign[] signs) {
        this.name = name;
        this.signs = signs;
    }

    List<Sign> signs() {
        return this.signs;
    }
}
```

This is my structure of my classes. Now, I would like to find out, whether two compared objects are equal or not. Let's say we have two Piece objects. How can I compare them in method Car.equals()? The problem here is how to find whether that object belongs to Piece or Brand subclass.

Comment: You are using composition AND inheritance on `Piece` inside of `Car`, I think you might be a bit confused.  A `Car` _has a_ `Piece`, a `Piece` is _not a_ `Car`.  I believe this should only use composition.

Comment: `Piece extends Car` doesn't look right. Are you even planning to allow using `Car car = new Piece();` and then `car.drive();` (or something Car should be able to do)? Same about `Brand extends Car`.

Comment: you should call equals on your instances of Piece, don't compare them using ==

Comment: Your model is a bit strange. Analogy with real life, a car is made of piece and has a brand. In you model, a `Piece`and a `Brand`are both cars. Do you expect a wheel to have `doors` and `windows`?

Comment: But if I moved attributes inside subclasses, how could I find which object to compare then?

Comment: @maxim789 If you are using composition you would override `equals` in each `Class` and use those `equals` inside of `Car.equals()`, AKA `Piece.equals` would be used inside of `Car.equals`.

Comment: you call `equals`on them (after having implemented this method of course)

Comment: `The problem here is how to find whether that object belongs to Piece or Brand subclass.` you can use `if(object instanceOf Piece)`

Answer (score 0):

Piece should not extend Car, but Car should be composed of Piece objects such as Window, Door, etctera. A Piece should implement equals/hashcode. Although having the interface explicitly define those functions doesn't mean the inherited class requires it, it still hints that it is necessary (refer to Comparator).

The equals contract requires the referenced members to be final for it to meet the contract. Brand overrides equals/hashcode to compare the brand name.

Window and Door need defining final members to make them truly unique but unfortunately none are provided in the question.

```java
   static class Car {

        private final Piece doors;

        private final Piece window;

        private final Brand brand;

        private final int hashCode;

        Car(Piece doors, Piece window, Brand brand) {
            this.doors = doors;
            this.window = window;
            this.brand = brand;
            this.hashCode = Objects.hash(doors, window, brand);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hashCode;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj instanceof Car) {
                Car otherCar = (Car) obj;

                return otherCar.doors.equals(doors) && otherCar.window.equals(window) && otherCar.brand.equals(brand);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    static class Window implements Piece {

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

    }

    static class Door implements Piece {

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return super.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return super.equals(obj);
        }

    }

    interface Piece {

        boolean equals(Object other);

        int hashCode();

    }

    static class Brand {

        private final String name;

        private final int hashCode;

        Brand(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.hashCode = Objects.hash(name);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (other instanceof Brand) {
                Brand otherBrand = (Brand) other;

                return otherBrand.name.equals(name);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return hashCode;
        }

    }
```